# Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Setup

Tags: sql, sql-server, installation, sql-server-2016-express

I get this error when I try to open the SQL Server installation file :

> The operating system on this computer or its service pack level does not meet the minimum requirements for SQL server 2016. to determine the .....***

By going to "Properties" and check the box "Run this program in
compatibility mode for: widows 7", Also my
problem was not solved.
My systems specifications are: Windows 7 Ultimate  /System Type: 64-bit /  RAM : 4.00GB / , Processor : Inrtel(R) Core(TM) i3-6100 CPU @3.70Hz

Also, I have the following versions for Microsoft .Net framework
software:*

- Microsoft .Net Framework 4.5 Multi-Targeting Pack
- Microsoft .Net Framework 4.5 SDK
- Microsoft .Net Framework 4.5.1 Multi-Targeting Pack
- Microsoft .Net Framework 4.5.1 Multi-Targeting Pack(ENU)
- Microsoft .Net Framework 4.5.1 SDK
- Microsoft .NetFramework 4.5.2 Multi-Targeting Pack
- Microsoft .Net Framework 4.5.2  Multi-Targeting Pack(ENU)
- Microsoft .Net Framework 4.6 SDK
- Microsoft .Net Framework 4.6 Targeting Pack
- Microsoft .Net Framework 4.6 Targeting Pack(ENU)
- Microsoft .Net Framework 4.8
- Microsoft .Net Framework 4.8 SDK
- Microsoft .Net Framework 4.8 Targeting Pack
- Microsoft .Net Framework 4.8 Targeting Pack(ENU)
- Microsoft .Net version Manager 1.0.0-beta5
  SQL Server Specifications:
  Microsoft® SQL Server 2016 Service Pack 2 (SP2)

Help me!

Comment: *"The operating system on this computer or its service pack level does not meet the minimum requirements for SQL server 2016"* I don't think that statement can be more obvious, I am afraid.

Comment: Also, Windows Vista certainly did not support SQL Server 2016.#

Comment: Side note, Windows 7 has been unsupported for some time now, and you should be using a more recent operating system.

Comment: are you sure? I mean should I change my windows? I think there is an easier solution

Comment: *"are you sure? "* Very, even before I looked at the documentation to copy it into my answer. *"I think there is an easier solution "* Yes, updating your version of windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is **literally** telling you the problem:

> The operating system on this computer or its service pack level does not meet the minimum requirements for SQL server 2016

This error cannot be any more clear; it is telling you you **cannot** install SQL Server 2016 on the version of Windows you are using: Windows 7 Ultimate.

This is confirmed in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-installing-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#operating-system-support) as well:

> ### Operating System support
>
> The following table shows which editions of SQL Server 2016 and 2017 are compatible with which versions of Windows:
>
> | SQL Server edition: | Enterprise | Developer | Standard | Web | Express |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Windows Server 2019 Datacenter | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
> | Windows Server 2019 Standard | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
> | Windows Server 2019 Essentials | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
> | Windows Server 2016 Datacenter | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
> | Windows Server 2016 Standard | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
> | Windows Server 2016 Essentials | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
> | Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
> | Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
> | Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
> | Windows Server 2012 R2 Foundation | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
> | Windows Server 2012 Datacenter | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
> | Windows Server 2012 Standard | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
> | Windows Server 2012 Foundation | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
> | Windows 10 IoT Enterprise | No | Yes | Yes | No | Yes |
> | Windows 10 Enterprise | No | Yes | Yes | No | Yes |
> | Windows 10 Professional | No | Yes | Yes | No | Yes |
> | Windows 10 Home | No | Yes | Yes | No | Yes |
> | Windows 8.1 Enterprise | No | Yes | Yes | No | Yes |
> | Windows 8.1 Pro | No | Yes | Yes | No | Yes |
> | Windows 8.1 Enterprise | No | Yes | Yes | No | Yes |
> | Windows 8 Pro | No | Yes | Yes | No | Yes |
> | Windows 8 | No | Yes | Yes | No | Yes |

Notice the complete lack of Windows 7 in the list.

Windows 7 has been completely unsupported for some time now anyway, so it's past time you upgrade your operating system, and it seems now you must if you want to use SQL Server 2016.

Comment: I updated my Windows from Windows 7 to Windows 10. But there is the same problem!

Comment: My new windows :  windows 10 pro ;

Comment: As as the above shows, that is supported by SQL Server 2016. I'mnot sure why you removed that solution tick, as this is still correct